# Replace NA values in a tibble with a list

Tags: r, replace, tibble

I have a tibble with a column whose values are all NA.
I have a list of values which I'd like to use to replace the NA values.
I'm looking for a tidy (if possible) way of replacing the NA values with the values from the list.
I've seen some answers that look like they might work, but the questions and their answers are too complicated for me to adapt.

An hour or two of Googling hasn't turned on the light for me.
Here is a simple example:

```
        PersonName <- c("Bob", "John", "Harry")
        Phone <- c(NA,NA,NA)
        t <- tibble(PersonName, Phone)
        numbers <- c("555-1212", "555-1234", "555-7856")
```

I haven't been able to create the necessary code to produce an example, but what I'd like to be able to do is replace the NA in each Phone column with the numbers in the list, sequentially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the number of `NA`s in the 'Phone' is equal to the 'numbers' `length`, can use `replace` with a logical condition

```
t1 <- t %>%
         mutate(Phone = replace(Phone, is.na(Phone), numbers))
t1
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  PersonName Phone   
#  <chr>      <chr>   
#1 Bob        555-1212
#2 John       555-1234
#3 Harry      555-7856
```

#### Update

Based on a discussion with the OP,  it seems that we ned to update only a subset of rows of the column corresponding to values in another column

```
gNodes2 <- gNodes %>% 
              mutate(DataType = replace(DataType, NodeType == "column", numbers))
```

Comment: Thank you. Here is a bit of elaboration that may change your answer: The real tilbble has a number of rows which shouldn't have the NA changes. I can easily subset the tibble with a filter to isolate only those rows which should be changed. I don't wish to create a new tibble (as indicated by the assignment operator in your answer), but to update the values in the specific column with the list values. Will I get what I want if I use the subsetted tibble rows on the left side of the assignment operator?

Comment: @CharlesKnell  Can you show the bit where it needs to be changedd

Comment: The subset from the real tibble is generated this way: gNodes[gNodes$NodeType == "column", ] and the the column I wish to update with the list is called DataType.

Comment: @CharlesKnell  If your `t <- gNodes[gNodes$NodeType == "column", ]` then `t1 <- t %>% mutate(DataType = replace(DataType, is.na(DataType), numbers))`

Comment: If I understand what you wrote, I will have to replace the rows in the original tibble with the newly-created "t" tibble. Can I, instead, substitute the subset (gNodes[gNodes$NodeType == "column", ]) for "t" on the left side of the assignment operator?

Comment: @CharlesKnell  It is not clear whether you need to `ffilter` the rows here if the intention is to replace the NAs preseent in 'DataType' corresponding to  the rows where "column" is present, i.e. `gNodes %>% mutate(Datatype = replace(DataType, is.na(DataType) & NodeType == "column", numbers))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197102/discussion-between-charles-knell-and-akrun).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the same as above (`length(Phone)` = `length(numbers)`) but with `cbind()` and `transmute()`:

```
t <- cbind(t, numbers) %>% transmute(PersonName, Phone = numbers) 
t

#  PersonName Phone
#1        Bob 555-1212
#2       John 555-1234
#3      Harry 555-7856
```